# Automatically run a command on start up?

Tags: wireless, command-line, autostart

I was kindly helped on this forum a few months ago to fix my Wifi. Only problem is I have to run the command in the terminal at the start of every session.Each time I need to run-

```
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

How can I make this process run automatically?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hmmm you probably got told half the story: check `/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf` and `/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf` and see if that module is blacklisted. if so put a # in front of the line

Comment: If it's only one command you can use this method:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login Also, you could write a script with all your commands and run it through the previous method.

Answer (score 1):

Try add command to **rc.local** file with nano or gedit. It runs commands, when startup process was ended. Do nothing by default. You can find it in `/etc/rc.local`