# Automatically Run a Command/script at startup

Tags: boot, command-line, server, autostart

This question is ALL over ubuntu, with MODS saying its duplicate, but I have found no good answers!

I want to run the command, (this will work for script as well)

```
sudo service deluged restart
```

at boot after everything is done, IE: last thing to run

I first found this post, marked duplicate

[Auto Run a command at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493632/automatically-run-a-command-on-start-up/493643#493643)

Which seth blocked from future help and linked to this post

[Start Applications at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

First off, I run a server, not a desktop (Which is what the linked "duplicate" guide shows you), so I can only use CLI based guides. Second those are 2 different questions.

Then there is this post

[Run a command at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580592/run-a-command-at-boot)

Marked as duplicate and linked to this question which may answer his specific question, but does not answer the question, run a command at boot.

[Why isn't my upstart service starting on system boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62812/why-isnt-my-upstart-service-starting-on-system-boot)

Anyway, there is more!, but what I am getting at is I know what I want is just ONE example of how to do this via CLI and simple. I am not a coder, but I can read code and edit it to suit my needs and understand it, i just can't create it so to speak.

As another mod (takkat) has said, this is a duplicate of a question relating to

[how to enable to disable services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657160/automatically-run-a-command-script-at-startup-yes-its-a-duplicate-no-good-ans?noredirect=1#comment945731_657160) but again my point is that this post, i am using

sudo service deluged restart

as an example on how to run a command/script at boot, not troubleshooting why a service is not runnnig. While rc.local may serve as a dirty fix for a problem i have, [deluge web-ui auto connect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657142/deluge-web-ui-only-auto-connects-when-i-restart-via-cli-not-upon-reboot-as-it-sh,) it can be used in a lot of other situations.

please try to answer the question directly, not give me links to what you think might help, and if it is a duplicate then link to a cli guide that covers HOW TO RUN A COMMAND/SCRIPT AT BOOT, because CLI guides can be used by both desktop and server users of Ubuntu.

Comment: Running an application (aka service) at boot is nicely elaborated here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services - Note that running a daemon on booting is different from running an application at login.

Comment: this post has nothing specific to daemons at boot, this applies to anything, the comannd could be sudo chmod 777 /home/user/sharedfiles/ -R the point is that it is broad, run ANY script or command after boot

Comment: the issue that started this is unrelated to the question, the  command I wanted to run at boot.. sudo service deluged restart, it was just an example

Comment: The link how to run scripts at startup has the answer I was looking for but it is a different question. My question is that I only needed to run a single command. But thanks for linking to a proper answer! There are multiple good options in that post

Answer (score 23, accepted):

rc.local has solved this for me, and although I have read is outdated *But kept around for compatibility*, if somebody has the updated, but JUST AS SIMPLE answer, please share as I will update my server.

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

You can use either calling a script in `rc.local` or directly run desired commands. Eg:

```
# By default this script does nothing.

/root/script.sh
(or)
sudo service deluged restart

exit 0
```

Cheers!

Comment: Doesn't work in version 20.

Comment: This answer does: https://askubuntu.com/a/816/475744

Comment: @EpicVoyage that is certainly an option, but I had issues w/ `@reboot` in `cron` where the service started to early and failed to start correctly. Still, if it works, I'd say that's possibly the best most universal approach.